# Need suggestion for icon for 'Unknown File Type'

Tags: icons, file-extension

I'm working on an attachment upload script for a professional / business website, which will display a list of all attachments with an icon representing their file type.

I have icons for most expected filetypes, word, pdf, excel etc...

But I need one for 'Unknown file type', just in case someone uploads a random file. Could anyone suggest an icon?

A quick google search produces mainly question marks, which I guess are fine but I'm wondering is there possibly a convention for this?

Comment: I think the convention would be to use a question mark.

Comment: commonly used icon (question mark) could be treated as a convention in this case

Comment: Note that this has just been [cross-posted to GD](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30336/need-suggestion-for-icon-for-unknown-file-type) so it may need to be migrated and merged.

Comment: Deleted from GD

Comment: Look at what the file browser of the OS does. Windows Explorer shows the standard "document" icon for a file with an extension that has not been registered. Other OS's file browsers probably do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on if you want to show "unknown" or "generic". Unknown (question mark) can be seen as a file that has some unknown properties, while in most cases, what the system wants to show is "this is a file that I don't have an icon for". I would therefore suggest a generic file icon.

[image]

If there may be cases where files without file ending are uploaded I guess the question mark would be appropriate since the system doesn't know what file type it is. In the other cases - the system **knows** what file type it is.

Comment: Cheers Henrik, this is what I was looking for. Thanks for the informative answer too.